# SQL QUERY - Max and length

Tags: mysql, sql

My goal is to find the name of the max length of the city. If there is more than one largest city, choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically.

I used it below but it's showing an error

```
select city, max(length(city))
from station
order by city asc
limit 1;
```

Comment: You need to use `group by` and order by the same criteria (desc)

Comment: Always good to see the full error message....

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the city(ies) where the length equals the maximum length, one option would be

```
select City, length(City)
from station
where Length(city) = (select Max(Length(city)) from station)
order by city
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to select the max, you just want to use it to order:

```
select city
from station
order by length(city) desc, city asc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a sub-select instead:

```
SELECT city, MAX(len_city)
FROM (SELECT city, LENGTH(city) AS len_city
      FROM station
      ORDER BY LENGTH(city) DESC, city)
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: An aggregate function without a group by will return 1 row only so limit is not useful..(and city will be non determinate in the case of draws) and there is no alphabetic order by city

Comment: The subquery ORDER BY does not affect the main query result order, incl. LIMIT 1.

Comment: @P.Salmon alphabetic ordering by city is default ascending in the sub-query, AFTER ordering by the longest city.

Comment: But as previously mentioned has no effect on main query

Comment: @jarlh original poster only appeared to want longest city, and in the case of a tie, pick the alphabetically first city to appear. Ordering the subquery this way results in the full list of cities ordered this way, and then selecting the longest ones and limiting to just the first result in the case of ties is why LIMIT 1 in the outer query.

Comment: LIMIT 1 will return a more or less random row, since there's no ORDER BY.